# Combining Aurelia and OnsenUI

Tags: onsen-ui, aurelia, onsen-ui2

for the past few years, I went from knockoutjs to durandaljs, then angular 1.x. Now I'm considering learning angular 2 and Aurelia. I'm not really attracted by Angular2 for now so I'm learning Aurelia.
Now the same way you can develop Mobile apps using Angular2 combined with Ionic or Onsen UI. I would like to know if it's possible to do the same with Aurelia and Onsen UI. It will be helpful If I can find examples or tutorial.
Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/sidloki/aurelia-onsenui

Comment: Ok I will look into it

Answer (score 2):

It won't be possible with Ionic as that is heavily tied to Angular. Some minor googling of "Onsen Aurelia" shows multiple examples of how to use Onsen with Aurelia.

Comment: I searched for "Onsen Aurelia". One of the results was for this page. The other was definitely NSFW.

Comment: Check out the first result in Google. It's a Stack Overflow question from 2015. Second result is a blog post from "onsentipster."

Comment: Do you mean this post?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747394/can-onsen-be-used-without-angular-i-would-rather-use-aurelia